# Converting compojure noir to Liberator

Tags: clojure, compojure, noir, liberator

I'm fairly new to clojure/compojure, but really love it. Naturally, started my exploration with Noir stack. Have written a POC app. Then, discovered Liberator -- makes a whole lot of sense. Just wondering, if anybody has ever migrated Noir applications to Liberator before. Any references to articles/blogs that cover this would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The goal for [Noir](http://www.webnoir.org/) and [Liberator](http://clojure-liberator.github.io/liberator/tutorial/getting-started.html) is slightly different. 
In simple words, you would use Noir to create website or web applications, and Liberator to create APIs, by exposing your resources for RESTful access. So to answer your main question, you would not really *migrate* from Noir to Liberator.

Also nowadays, Noir has actually been deprecated for compojure+[lib-noir](http://www.luminusweb.net/docs/routes.md#restricting_access)

Just in case, the main frameworks to build web applications these days in Clojure would be:

- [Luminus](http://www.luminusweb.net/)
- [Pedestal](http://pedestal.io/),
- (and to a lesser degree) [ClojureScriptOne](http://clojurescriptone.com/)
- (and as stated above) pure [compojure](https://github.com/weavejester/compojure) + libnoir

Comment: You happen to have any elaborated thoughts on Luminus vs. Pedestal?

Answer (score 1):

I was learning most clojure/compojure from the the book http://pragprog.com/book/dswdcloj/web-development-with-clojure which is still in beta. Seems that it's out of date before it even published. The Pedestal seems to be very very interesting and exciting. Though, what do people think, I know it's hard to predict, but what is a possibility of Pedestal becoming a next defacto standard replacing compojure+libnoir? Just have very scarce resources, and trying to make correct choices early in the game. Making simple decision is difficult these days.